# How to put a jQuery code into one file which will be referenced by all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a login popup that will pop up on every page of my site.  What I want to do is once the user clicks submit, to have a single JS file where the jQuery code for handling that request lives, and makes an AJAX call to validate the parameters in the DB.

I am able to get the pop up box to pop up. And the form loads.  I am thinking my jQuery code will live in a separate imported file and look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        var some_params= $("#param").val();

        var dataString = 'Some url to send to ajax';

        if( params validated ok )
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/add_problem.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(json)
                {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();    
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

So my question is how do I make this get invoked only when the right form is submitted? The form would have some id="some_name" but I don't really understand how to make this jQuery code get executed only when that form element is called.

And here is the form I am calling to display in the popup:

```
<?php
         echo '<div id="login_div">
         <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
         <p>
             <label for="name"><span>Your Email:</span></label> <input type="text" name="email" />
         </p>
         <p>
             <label for="name"><span>Your Password:</span></label> <input type="password" name="user_pass">
         </p>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"  />
         </p>
         </form>
         </div>


<p>
    <a href="http://www.problemio.com/auth/create_profile.php">Create Account</a> | <a href="http://www.problemio.com/auth/forgot_password.php">Reset Pass</a>
</p>
         ';
?>
```

and here is the problemio.js contents with the jQuery to handle the login form submit:

```
// javascript library

// login_form

$(function()
{
    $("#login_form input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        console.log("test");
        alert("1");
//      var name = $("#problem_name").val();
//      var problem_blurb = $("#problem_blurb").val();

//      var dataString = 'problem_name='+ name + '&problem_blurb=' + problem_blurb;

//      if(name=='' || problem_blurb == '')
//      {
//          $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
//          $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
///     }
//      else
//      {
//          $.ajax({
//              type: "POST",
//              url: "/problems/add_problem.php",
//              dataType: "json",
//              data: dataString,
//              success: function(json)
//              {
//                  $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
//                  $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
//                  
///                 // Here can update the right side of the screen with the newly entered information
//                  //alert (json);
//          
//                  new_string = "<h2>Most Recently Added Problems</h2>";

                    // Have to figure out how to make this work with the DOM.

//              }
//          });
//      }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: So really, you just don't want the script to be 'available'/loaded until a valid form is submitted? I wouldn't bother. It's small enough to be included in your application without being fiddly. However, I WOULD wrap it up into a function that's invoked conditionally, rather than just blindly binding the click to all submit inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.  First, when you place the code above into a separate javascript file, be sure to remove the <script ..> and </script> HTML tags.

Next, alter the following line:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function()
```

To instead say:

```
$("#loginform input[type=submit]").click(function()
```

And then set id="loginform" on your <form> tag.

Comment: I just did that, and I get one problem. The wrong jQuery code is being triggered after form submit.  It is here: http://www.problemio.com after pressing "upvote" - would you know why a wrong jQuery submit case might get triggered?

Comment: The wrong code is being applied because there is another block of code attached to all input[type=submit] that is not in the problemio.js file.  It has code like this at the top: var name = $("#problem_name").val();  Be sure to find this block of code and then change the $('input[type=submit]') to $('#somethingelse input[type=submit]') like we did with the login form.

Comment: Thanks, just getting the hang of it :)

Comment: your suggestion worked to not get that other form to get invoked.  But I still can not get the right form invoked.  I put some logging statements there, but it never gets to them :( Any idea what else is wrong with my site :)

Comment: The login form popup is hidden by #mypopup {display:none}.  I do not see where you are showing the login form.  In other words I can't figure out how to test the code out on your site :) :)

Comment: I just added all the involved code. What is puzzling me is that the form has id="login_form" and the jQuery code has  $("#login_form input[type=submit]").click(function() so I was assuming it should match up, but somehow it doesn't.  Is there something else that can be the problem?

Comment: Do me a favor and add references to jquery.min.js in your auth/log_in.php page.  Also, add a reference to your js/problemio.js file.  Then test on your login form there.  Let me know when you've done this and I'll take a peek.

Comment: @Alfredo just added it, but getting syntax errors.  Can we try to resolve it in the chat room? (Sorry, I am green at JS and jQuery).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4080/discussion-between-genadinik-and-alfred-fazio)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to attach a handler to the form submit event.  First you'll need to select your form via the id:

```
$("#some_form_id").submit(function() {
    // the code you have in the click event above goes here.
});
```

Comment: thanks - this would go in my jQuery code instead of some other code? Where would I place this?

Comment: Replace your current line `$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {` with the first line of my example code.  That should be all that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can specific the form you want to trigger the jquery. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure, just right-click this webpage and read its html code.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>`

And also, binding the the function to form.submit is much better than to the submit button.

`$('formid').submit(function(){blablabla;return false;})`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to handle the click event for every submit on the page without using ids, you can always use the `this` keyword in the click event to find the sender and then find the parent `form`.